# JavaCard simple applet not displaying text

Tags: javacard

I have the following problem:

[image]

Many simple examples found in internet, but no success.

The problem is: My menu entry comes in the STK menu, but if I select it, nothing happens. I tried to display text on event EVENT_MENU_SELECTION.

```
package helloStk;

import javacard.framework.*;
import sim.access.*;
import sim.toolkit.*;

public class helloStk extends Applet 
  implements ToolkitConstants, ToolkitInterface
{
  private static final byte CMD_QUALIFIER = (byte)0x80;

  private byte[] menuEntry = {'M','y','M','e','n','u'};
  private byte[] textBuf = {'H','e','l','l','o'};

  private ToolkitRegistry reg;
  private SIMView gsmFile;

  public helloStk() {
    //Get the GSM application reference
    gsmFile = SIMSystem.getTheSIMView();
    enter code here`enter code here`
    reg = ToolkitRegistry.getEntry();

    reg.initMenuEntry(menuEntry,
                      (short) 0, 
                      (short) menuEntry.length,
                      PRO_CMD_DISPLAY_TEXT,
                      false,
                      (byte) 0,
                      (short) 0);
  }

  public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength)
    throws ISOException
  {

    helloStk dt = new helloStk();
    dt.register();
  }

  public void processToolkit(byte event)
    throws ToolkitException
  {
    ProactiveHandler ph = ProactiveHandler.getTheHandler();

    if (event == EVENT_MENU_SELECTION) {


       ph.init((byte) PRO_CMD_DISPLAY_TEXT, (byte) CMD_QUALIFIER, DEV_ID_DISPLAY);
       ph.appendTLV((byte)(TAG_TEXT_STRING | TAG_SET_CR),
                    textBuf,
                    (short) 0, 
                    (short) textBuf.length);
      ph.send();
    }
  }


  public void process(APDU apdu) {
    if (selectingApplet()) {
      return;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you please try `reg.initMenuEntry(..., PRO_CMD_SELECT_ITEM, ...)` instead of `reg.initMenuEntry(..., PRO_CMD_DISPLAY_TEXT, ...)`?

Comment: Ok, let me try it Sir. Thanks

Comment: hi @vojta Gotten the same error:  Install applet failed
INSTALL (for install) response check failed with SW 6F 00

Comment: You should try comment out lines from your constructor and see which one causes the exception...

Comment: Vojta, when I comment  this line, the app installs successfully. But I want a menu, thats why I need to initialize it. reg.initMenuEntry(menuEntry,
                      (short) 0, 
                      (short) menuEntry.length,
                      PRO_CMD_DISPLAY_TEXT,
                      false,
                      (byte) 0,
                      (short) 0);

Comment: Surround that line with try-catch and check if `ToolkitException` is thrown or not. If yes, call `getReason` on the exception and post the result of this call (you will have to check all possible values).

Comment: Like this: `try { reg.initMenuEntry(...); } catch (ToolkitException e) {short reason = e.getReason(); if (reason == ToolkitException.SOMETHING) { throw e} }`

Comment: Done this this way but still experiencing the same error.  I am using JLoad to load the cap file to the sim card.   try{
         reg.initMenuEntry(menuEntry,
                      (short) 0, 
                      (short) menuEntry.length,
                      PRO_CMD_SELECT_ITEM,
                      false,
                      (byte) 0,
                      (short) 0); 
    }
    catch(ToolkitException e){
     
     short reason = e.getReason(); 
     
    if (reason == ToolkitException.SOMETHING) { throw e}
     
    }

Comment: @JamesJavaCard May I have your email address please?

Comment: @Abraham jamesfrankird@gmail.com

Comment: I'd be careful what I would call and initialize from the static install method and constructor. Java Card has some specific requirements for byte code in static methods and such.

Comment: I'd try and remove the calls from the constructor and move them to a method. Then make sure you can call them through normal APDU processing. If they do not work, then find the exception. Currently you are working in the dark.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes can I have an example kindly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should first call the register() method for the Applet instance and then retrieve the ToolkitRegistry entry.